# Add 1 second to minimum date in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How do you add 1 second to the minimum date column in the datepicker in Oracle Apex? By using +1d, I can add 1 day and by using +1m, I can add 1 month. But how do you actually add 1 hour or 1 second? I have a date field called `:INF_BIRTH_TIME` and I would want `INF_DISCHARGE_TIME`to be 1 hour later than `:INF_BIRTH_TIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way to add time to `date` or `timestamp` fields is by using `INTERVAL`. The documentation is confusing to read, so I'll just give some examples:

```
select sysdate, 
  sysdate + interval '1' second,
  sysdate + interval '1' hour 
from dual;
```

In your case, I think you'll want to do:

```
:INF_DISCHARGE_TIME := :INF_BIRTH_TIME + interval '1' hour;
```

It's up to you whether to do that in a computation, the Source field on INF_DISCHARGE_TIME, a page process, or something else.

Comment: Oracle Apex does not accept this kind of syntax in minimum date field.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. So - create a hidden page item, `:MIN_DISCHARGE`, and set it as described above. Then set the minimum date on INF_DISCHARGE_TIME to `&MIN_DISCHARGE.`

Comment: I set it as you said but Oracle Apex kept telling me the syntax is wrong. ```:MIN_DISCHARGE for item INF_DISCHARGE_TIME does not match YYYYMMDDHH24MI, DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIPM format.```

Comment: As kfinity told you, you need to set the attribute to `&MIN_DISCHARGE.` (i.e. you have to use substitution syntax, not bind variable syntax)